# Memory leaks because of MRR memory management

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I've got some code for no-arc project

```
@interface TRSSImageDownloader()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *activeDownloadData;

@end
@implementation TRSSImageDownloader

@synthesize activeDownloadData = _activeDownloadData;

-(id)init {
       self = [super init];
       if (self) {
              _activeDownloadData = [NSMutableData new];
       }
       return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [_activeDownloadData release];
    [super dealloc];
 }
```

It's working, but when I'm testing it through "Profile"->"Leaks", it shows memory leaks on `activeDownloadData`

Comment: There is no leak in this code. Where is the rest of the code? What does the static analyser tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaks only tells you where the leaked memory was allocated. That does not tell you specifically where your failure to correctly release is. Most likely you either assign something to `_activeDownloadData` incorrectly somewhere else, or you're leaking all of `TRSSImageDownloader` (and so, by indirection, also leaking `_activeDownloadData`).

The most common cause of this problem is direct use of ivars. If you use accessors everywhere (except `init` and `dealloc`), these problems tend to go away easily. If you use ivars directly inside of the object, you will tend to have these kinds of problems. Without accessors, you need to audit every place you assign the ivar directly and make sure you're releasing the old value correctly.

Converting to ARC is of course the recommended solution if at all possible.